# How to create 2d arrayobject for a custom class

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, nullpointerexception, jframe, jbutton

I have custom class called ButtonList, like a list of buttons, i am adding all the buttons that are going into the window to that 2d array object of button list.

```
ButtonList[][] buttonList;
buttonList = new ButtonList[5][3];
```

and I'm constantly getting Null pointer error  when im am trying to add the 
JButtons to the buttonList.

```
this.buttonList[column][row].addButton(buttonImage);
```

ButtonList and addButton method looks like so:

```
static class ButtonList{
    int column = 0;
    int row = 0;
    JButton[][] arrayButton = new JButton[this.column][this.row];

    void addButton(JButton BUTTON){ 
        arrayButton[this.column][this.row] = BUTTON;
        System.out.println("Row: " + this.row + " Column: " + this.column);
        this.column += 1;
        this.row += 1;
        System.out.println("button inserted at " + this.row);
    }//end addButton
```

what is it that i am doin wrong?
thanks

Comment: you should initialize your arrayButton as `arrayButton[this.column][this.row] = new JButton();` in `addButton()` method.

Answer (score 0):

```
        int column = 0;
        int row = 0;
        JButton[][] arrayButton = new JButton[this.column][this.row];
```

You initialize your array before your constructor get called. So at this point your column and row are still 0. You initialize then an array of [0][0]. This is why later on you get a null pointer exception even though you may have changed the values of row and column in your constructor or later on in any method. But at the time of the creation they were 0.
Moreover

```
           arrayButton[this.column][this.row] = BUTTON;
```

This is quite probable to give you a out of bounds exception because arrays in java are 0 indexed so your valid range is from [0,column-1][0,row-1] so you may want to fix this as well.

Comment: i didnt create a constructor to the class.. its the default constructor. After your suggestion however, i created my constructor which looks like so: 

JButton[][] arrayButton;


ButtonList(){
   arrayButton = new JButton[this.column][this.row];
  }

Comment: Ok great still you need to give your column and row correct sizes so that you can really create the array. Try to column and row a value of 4 and see the flow of your program.

Comment: no mate, still no dice :( this is getting very annoying. would you like a copy of the code?

Comment: @sabbibJAVA yes this would be very helpful

Answer (score 0):

```
JButton[][] arrayButton = new JButton[this.column][this.row];
```

this line create an 2d array (without initialization), and infact is equivalent to this:

```
JButton[][] arrayButton = new JButton[0][0];
```

0 happens to be the value of the column and row at that time. Changing the value of these two variables does not take any effect on the array it self.

Solution:
   If you know in advance the max value of column and row, use that value for array creation. If not, use ArrayList, you will be able to change your size later.

Comment: it still doesnt work, i have shared the code above comment. id would be great if you would be able to help by taking a look

Comment: What are the total number of JButton?